# How to get the result in percentage form using nv.d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart, nvd3.js

I am using nv.d3.js for generating a simple bar chart, and I'm getting the proper results. But what is want is , to get the result of y axis in percentage instead of the data itself. For ex, my data is as follows :-

```
          data2 = [
              {
                "key": "How many Employees are there in company",
                "values": [
                  { 
                    "label" : "0-10" ,
                    "value" : 29
                  } , 
                  { 
                    "label" : "10-20" , 
                    "value" : 0
                  } , 
                  { 
                    "label" : "20-30" , 
                    "value" : 49
                  } , 
                  { 
                    "label" : "30-40" , 
                    "value" : 30
                  } , 
                  { 
                    "label" : "40-50" ,
                    "value" : 8
                  } , 
                  { 
                    "label" : "50-60" , 
                    "value" : 98
                  } , 
                  { 
                    "label" : "60-70" , 
                    "value" : 13
                  } , 
                  { 
                    "label" : "70-80" , 
                    "value" : 5
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
```

And i want the result of "value" in percentage on the top of each bar instead of its value itself. For 98(the highest one) it should be 100% , for value 49, it should be 50% (calculated on the base of highest value) and so on. Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: What chart are you using??

Comment: Hello @shabeer90 , I am using Discrete Bar Chart.

Comment: You need to calculate the percentages yourself. Passing that data to NVD3, you only need to change the tick label format to include a % sign.